# Is there a way to add table header scope attributes using tagpdf?

Tags: tagged-pdf, tagpdf

I am using the excellent tagpdf latex package to create accessibiilty compliant pdfs from latex. I am able to create tags as expected but am having some trouble using the "raw"  option to add some custom  tags.

In particular, for tables to be compliant with accessibility standards the headers need to have the "scope" attribute set to being either "Both" or "Columns" or "Rows".

For example in the raw pdf this appears for a header cell as attribute "A"  of the header cell with attributes {'/O': '/Table', '/Scope': 'Both'}.

I cant quite figure out how to create this tag in tagpdf. MWE is below

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tagpdf}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % 
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}

\tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | }
\hline
\tagstructbegin{tag=TR}
\tagstructbegin{tag=TH}
\tagmcbegin{tag=TH,raw=/Scope (Both)}
h1
  \tagmcend
\tagstructend & 
\tagstructbegin{tag=TH}
\tagmcbegin{tag=TH}
h2
  \tagmcend
\tagstructend 
  \\ \hline
     \tagstructbegin{tag=TR}
\tagstructbegin{tag=TH}
\tagmcbegin{tag=TH}
r1
  \tagmcend
\tagstructend 
& 
 \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
 \tagmcbegin{tag=TD}
 h2
  \tagmcend
 \tagstructend 
 \tagstructend  
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\tagstructend

\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

This compiles, and the other tags are fine, but the scope tag does not come through and I think it is because my use of raw isnt right.

Comment: If I got the specification right, Scope belongs into the attribute object of the structure element, not in the MC-marker. There is currently no key to create such an attribute object, but it shouldn't be too difficult to add it. Please open an issue at https://github.com/u-fischer/tagpdf/issues so that I don't forget it. Beside this you should use `\tagpdfsetup{activate-all}` to get the complete structure.

Comment: Side remark: I doubt that the attribute is really required, at least the test of adobe didn't complain. But you are missing the  Thead/TBody level.

Comment: Thank you! Ive registered the issue and I really appreciate your help, the tagpdf package is amazing!

Comment: Well I'm glad if I get some feedback. And if you have real examples to share I would be glad about them too.

Comment: I uploaded a new version to the github repo which adds an attribute key for structelem. See https://github.com/u-fischer/tagpdf/issues/10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 0.42 (currently only in the github) you can add the attributes either directly or as attribute class like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{activate-all,uncompress}

\ifluatex\else
\pdfcatalog{/Lang (en-UK)}
\pdfinfo {/Title (Title)}
\fi

\tagpdfsetup
{
 newattribute = {TH-col} { <</Owner /Table /Scope /Column>> },
 newattribute = {TH-row} { <</Owner /Table /Scope /Row>>    },
 newattribute = {TH-both}{ <</Owner /Table /Scope /Both>>   },
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} %
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}

\tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | }
\hline
\tagstructbegin{tag=THead}
 \tagstructbegin{tag=TR}
  \tagstructbegin{tag=TH,attribute= {TH-both}}
   \tagmcbegin{tag=TH}
   h1
   \tagmcend
   \tagstructend &
  \tagstructbegin{tag=TH,attribute-class={TH-row}}
    \tagmcbegin{tag=TH}
    h2
    \tagmcend
  \tagstructend
 \tagstructend %TR
 \tagstructend %Thead
  \\ \hline
 \tagstructbegin{tag=TBody}
   \tagstructbegin{tag=TR}
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
    \tagmcbegin{tag=TD}
    r1
    \tagmcend
    \tagstructend %TD
&
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
    \tagmcbegin{tag=TD}
    h2
    \tagmcend
    \tagstructend
  \tagstructend %TR
 \tagstructend %TBody
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\tagstructend

\tagstructend
\end{document}
```